# How one can evaluate $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(4t, e^t)}{f(\sin2t, \cos2t)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, partial-derivative

How one can evaluate $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(4t, e^t)}{f(\sin2t, \cos2t)}$$ 
where

> $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with continuous partial derivatives and $f(0,1)=0$ and $f_x(0,1)=1$ and $f_y(0,1)=2$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if why did someone downvote this question?

Comment: Can you follow the given hint?

Comment: @ user, I get it now  , but I coudnot find the limit

Comment: I've added some more step. Can you conclude form here?

Comment: @user62498 I downvoted the question because it sounds like "here is my homework, do it for me".

Comment: @Botnod, I'm so sorry, but I don't have no idea abuot this problem

Comment: I understand it. But one thing you could do is to calculate the limit for a specific function. The easiest one would be $f(x,y)=x+2(y-1)$.

Comment: @Botond, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(0,1)$ and for $(h,k)\to (0,0)$

$$f(h,1+k)=(1,2)\cdot (h,k)+o(\sqrt{h^2+k^2})$$

therefore

- $f(4t, e^t)=f(4t, 1+t+o(t))=6t+o(t)$
- $f(\sin2t, \cos2t)=f(2t+o(t),1+o(t))=2t+o(t)$

Comment: Isn't $\sin(2t)=2t+o(t)$?

Comment: @Botond Opsss yes of course! I fix the typo. Thanks